# Matching object to list member in Drools

Tags: drools, rule-engine, rule

I've currently got a series of objects of class A and an object which is a List of objects of Class B in Drools Working Memory. Both classes have an ID attribute.

I need to run a rule to check if there is an object of Class A in memory that matches an ID from the list of Class B. (In essence, running a search for each element of the list to check if its ID matches an object of Class A)

To make things clearer, I've got something of the sort in memory:

```
class A{
    ID : String
}

List[B]  where:

Class B{
    ID: String
}
```

I've been trying to structure a rule query around this to no avail. Ideas? (Still relatively new to Drools)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps like this:

```
when
  $list: List()
  B($id: ID) from $list
  A(ID == $id)
then
```

Using a container as a fact is usually considered (at least by me) as being an antipattern. Things are easier if the B's are facts.

```
A($id: ID)
B(ID == $id)
```

You can still insert the List if you think this will ever be useful.

Comment: Thanks. I was actually inserting them individually as facts at first but the List is actually an attribute of an object I'm updating via rules based on this List...which makes it more complicated to update the main object.

Giving this a shot, thanks @laune